# How do they guarantee the celebrities' safety?

Tags: im-a-celebrity

During the TV show [I'm a Celebrity](http://www.itv.com/imacelebrity) contestants are often put in confined spaces with wild animals. Frequently these are bugs and magots but often they're nastier creatures like snakes or big lizards.

In 2016 Martin Roberts was put in a trial to collect stars and came face to face with a huge hissing lizard whipping it's tail. Scenes like this are fairly typical:

[image]

Taken from the [ITV Pages](http://www.itv.com/imacelebrity/highlights/carl-snakes-in-a-drain-trial-pictures)

Presumably the show has a whole raft of health and safety with it but how to they make sure that these animals are not going to bite or injure the contestants?

Comment: What threat would these animals provide the celebrity? There are non-venomous snakes, and even venomous ones, can be drained, or defanged.

Comment: I assume that firstly they take allergy details from each contestant, then ensure that all the insects they interact with are both non-venomous/poisonous and wouldn't cause an allergic reaction if bit. For some other insects, such as maggots, they wouldn't cause any harm anyway as they only eat dead flesh.

Comment: Except the most recent series had a celeb (think it was Wayne Bridge) come into contact with a crocodile. Venomous or not, that bad boy is going to do some damage if he decides to attack.

Answer (score 1):

### They can't completely guarantee safety overall (it's an open jungle), but take steps to make sure tasks and the camp are as safe as possible

As noted in [multiple](https://www.mirror.co.uk/tv/tv-news/10-reasons-im-celebrity-lot-6825143) [articles](https://metro.co.uk/2015/11/10/im-a-celebrity-10-surprising-facts-about-the-safety-of-contestants-you-may-not-have-known-5492665/),

- Production staff will test each task prior to the start of the series. This is to check that challenges are possible to complete, and will highlight any possible safety concerns.
- Contestants are apparently responsible for their own safety, and this is contractual.
- Crew are constantly monitoring the camp for potentially dangerous animals, which are removed when identified.

Ultimately though, as noted in the comments above, [the animals used in the trials are very unlikely to be able to kill you](https://www.bustle.com/p/are-the-im-a-celebrity-bugs-animals-deadly-the-fear-is-more-than-psychological-13217203), and at most might give you a little bite. So it's more likely that you'll be psychologically injurered!